# Python threading error group argument must be None for now

Tags: python

I'm running into the following error, any ideas on what could be causing it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    click_thread = RegisterC(delay, button)
   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 781, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now" 
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

```
delay = 0.01
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='w')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='s')


class RegisterC(threading.Thread):
    def init(self, delay, button):
        super(RegisterC, self).init()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(20,60))
                time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = MouseController()
keyboard = KeyboardController()
click_thread = RegisterC(delay, button)
click_thread.start()
```

Comment: `def init(self, delay, button)`  did you mean `def __init__(...):`?  It looks like you're trying to override `Thread.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

The magic method that's called during object initialization is `__init__` not `init`, you need to apply this fix :

```
class RegisterC(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(RegisterC, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True
```

As you called your method `init`, you didn't overwrite the base class constructor, so the arguments given to `RegisterC` on this line `click_thread = RegisterC(delay, button)` were passed to `Thread.__init__` which expect`group` as first argument and assert it to be `None`.